# Convert a String representation of byte[] back to an byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, base64

I have a `String` variable say `string` that I converted into `byte[]` and then I encoded the same using `Base64` in as `byte[]` say `encodedByteArr`. Using the below code:

```
String string = "Test";
byte[] encodedByteArr= null;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(check);
encodedByteArr= Base64.encodeBase64(bos.toByteArray());
oos.flush();
oos.close();
bos.close();
System.out.println("Encoded value is:- "+encodedByteArr);
```

Output is:

> Encoded value is:- [B@5fd0d5ae

Now, I receive the same encoded value in another method as a `String`, which means:

```
String string = "[B@5fd0d5ae";
```

And it is nothing but a `String` representation of `byte[]` which I generated in above code.

Now my task is to actually decode the value and get back the original text back, that is `"Test"`.

And for that, I want the `String` representation of `byte[]` back to a an `byte[]` without losing its integrity.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: You have actually solved your problem already (I think).  The problem is that you are printing the array the wrong way ... and the output makes you *think* you have done it incorrectly.

Comment: You'll never decode anything out of `[B@5fd0d5ae`. You'll need a more meaningful encoding than the default `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

All Java arrays print like that.  It's the way they work.  If you want to print the contents of the array, you have to use a static method from `java.util.Arrays`.

```
System.out.println("Encoded value is:- "+Arrays.toString(encodedByteArr));
```

It's kind of dumb, but that's the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my task is to actually decode the value and get back the original text back

It sounds like you have a Base64-encoded string that you want to decode to yield the original string?

In Java 8, you can do

```
import java.util.Base64;
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
String original = new String(decoded);
```

A full "round trip" would look like:

```
String original = "Hello";
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(original.getBytes());
String encodedString = new String(encodedBytes);
System.out.println(encodedString);  // "SGVsbG8="

byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
System.out.println(decodedString);  // "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("decoded raw byte: ");
for (byte singleByte:encodedByteArr) {
    System.out.print((char)singleByte);
}
```

Will return the string representation of byte to the output.
(not so efficient)